# Implementing Federated security using Thinktecture IdentityServer v2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, ws-federation, thinktecture-ident-server

## Infrastructure layout

BLUE lines initiate the request to login.

RED lines is the response after successful login.  I hit a 404 going from idp(janie-pc/ofsidentityservice) to fp(janie-pc/federationservice).

[image: infrastructure layout]

## Configuration

[image: thinktecture identity server v2 configuration]

What do I need to do to get this flow working?

I'm using the latest release (v2.3): https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/releases

It looks like i might need to specify a redirect url but what does thinktecture need the url to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect back to the /issue/hrd endpoint of the relay.

Comment: setting the Redirect URL to the hrd solved the issue.  flow is 100% working thanks! Why doesn't the idp already know how to redirect automatically? - couldn't the relay specify the reply to url?

Comment: That would be a security issue. This way it would be possible to transmit the token to some random server.

Comment: I get the open redirect security problem.  In this example I have already specified the Identity Provider at the federation service AND I specified the federation service as a relying party at the idp - based on that trust alone couldn't we have a signed token for reply_to that could be validated and not have the open redirect problem?  Hard coding the redirect url works today - but possibly a feature request.

Comment: Well - that's not how WS-Federation is specified ;) The redirect URI is part of the contract two token services share.